# Drupal 6 Migration

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404, migrating

Short question, hopefully short answer is needed.

I migrated my drupal 6 site from live server, to localhost.

I copied all data from live server to /var/www, changed the settings.php to the new mysql database login information.

The main page opens flawlessly on localhost.

Problem is, every other sub-page. I get 404 error on every link.

What did I forget to update? I checked .htaccess didn't find anything there, that I think is relevant information, but I am not an expert in drupal systems nor in migrating them.

Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your localhost will run your htaccess file.

Turn clean URLs off.

Check your DB and replace any calls to your live server with your localhost.

That should sort it out. If not post some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have emptied the cache tables (apologies if you have already done this).

If you can get to it, admin -> performance -> clear caches, otherwise go to the DB and truncate all tables with cache in their name.

Comment: Clean URL was the problem, but thanks for the advice on the flush!